# GAE Golang implementing some unique request queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, go, request

I have a Google App Engine Go application that is handling real-time notifications from a third party server. Those notifications need to be logged and processed more or less on the spot. However, the third party server has a nasty habit of sending two requests at the same time, sometimes 1 milisecond apart from one another - too fast to even make a datastore / memcache write indicating a semaphore.

I am wondering if there is a way to handle such concurrent requests neatly? Ideally I would want to put them on some stack that would be guaranteed to process items on it one at a time. Is something like this possible in GAE Golang?

Comment: a stack would change the order in which requests are processed in relation to how they come in i.e. LIFO. A queue is what you're looking for. If the identifier of the last processed request matches the first element in the queue then skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a memcache add for the unique identifier of the message with a short timeout (doesn't actually matter).  If the add succeeds, process the message.